# How can I sort a polygon list in AN based on the center distance to some specific point?

Tags: animation-nodes

I think that the question is self explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always there are multiple ways to do this. Here is the most flexible:

[image]

Basicly you give each polygon a number (distance to the point) which will be used as sorting key in the Sort List node.

The first element in the polygon list and the first element in the distances list belong to each other, same with the second, etc.