# Matter of Sorting element - What is Custom Sort?

Tags: animation-nodes

I am investigating this Sort node in Animation Nodes. I found it to be confusing especially with Custom sort and Key List. I cannot guess what this is for.

[image]

[image]

Is there a documentation or can anyone help me to understand this Sort node a little better.

NOTE: Btw, I think the sorting of Text Sequence Script in VSE has issue. I have it happening on my latest live noding video.

Thanks.

Comment: hey, did you read the answer to your question?

Comment: I just noticed this answer, I will test it with strings. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Custom Sort:** In general, you can sort a list of objects by key. E.g. if you have a list of customers, you can sort them by various keys such as first name, last name, customer number, etc.

**Key** - a key for a custom sort, which can be written as an expression using the attributes of your list element `e`. For example, you can enter `e.location.x` as as a *Key* to sort the list of objects based on their *x* location.

**Key List** - list of sorting keys. If your sorting key is not an attribute of the objects in the list, you can plug the list of key into the *Key List* Node. For example, look at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56388/how-can-i-sort-a-polygon-list-in-an-based-on-the-center-distance-to-some-specifi) answer, where the polygons are sorted according to the distance to some point using Sort List node. Computed distances are used as a Key List.